# Kdenlive Effect Properties Tab Greyed Out

Tags: kdenlive

The Properties tab on [Kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/en/) is greyed out.

How do I fix this? Google has not been helpful.

Comment: Please click [edit] and tell us a) which version number of Kubuntu you're using and b) which version and release number of Kubuntu (or Ubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Ubuntu Budgie, Xubuntu, et al).  Also, c) Version number of Kdenlive? Please don't use Add Comment; use [edit] as that info belongs in the question.

Comment: https://forum.kde.org/search.php?st=0&sk=t&sd=d&sr=posts&keywords=kdenlive may also be helpful.